# How to move and fade out any View with Animation

Tags: android, animation, move, fadeout, alpha

Ok, so I have a View where its being animated with the following code:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.productPage_parentLayout_RL);

ImageView iv = new ImageView( ProductPage.this );
imageLoader.DisplayImage(FULL_PRODUCT_INFO.getFirstImage(), iv);

Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, helper.getDeviceWidth() - 100,0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

rl.addView(iv);
```

With this code, the view starts from the left side of the screen and moves to almost the end of the screen, but I also want to fade-out the view and hide/destroy it in the end. I tried to search anything related to this, but couldn't find any.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
ObjectAnimator move=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "translationY",100f);
                    move.setDuration(3000);
    ObjectAnimator alpha1=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "alpha",0.5f);
                    alpha1.setDuration(1000);

                    ObjectAnimator alpha2=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "alpha",0);
                    alpha2.setDuration(2000);
    AnimatorSet animset=new AnimatorSet();
                    animset.play(alpha2).before(alpha1).with(move);
                    animset.start();
```

Comment: ObjectAnimator is for API 11 and higher. I need to use it starting from API 8.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        a.setFillAfter(true);
        iv.startAnimation(a);

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        set.addAnimation(animation)
        set.addAnimation(a)
        set.setFillAfter(true);
        iv.startAnimation(set);

    set.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Almost... I also did use this method, but it needs to fade-out when moving and hide when it reaches the end.

Comment: in this case, you need to use AnimationSet